# `gcloud compute instances create-with-container --public-dns` - what does this do?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-os

I'm looking to get public DNS names for my compute instances, and I notice that in the beta for [create-with-container there's the --public-dns flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/create-with-container#--public-dns). I've created a container with this flag, but I can't see any kind of public DNS name when I do an inspect.

Is there any way I can get a public DNS name for my container without starting a load balancer etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look to the documentation "[Creating an instance with a PTR record](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-ptr-record)"

The equivalent with gcloud commands is

```
gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME] \
    --image-family [IMAGE_FAMILY] \
    --image-project [IMAGE_PROJECT] \
    --public-ptr --public-ptr-domain [DOMAIN_NAME]
```

Comment: I am not looking to create a PTR record linked to my domain. Instead, I want a public DNS name for my compute instance (e.g. `[INSTANCE_NAME].project-id.googlecloud.com`). This --public-dns flag is under-documented and I am trying to understand it.